# LINQ/XML - loop through results of a query (is returning an element lower than expected)

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to loop through the results of a LINQ/XML query. 
I can return a string result when I use .Element(1).Value, but now I want to return all Elements() and loop through them.

I display the value of result in the loop, and it shows only the element "Name" and it's value.  I was expecting the value to include all the XML of the "Character".

You can run and see results here: 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/g0nURp

I'm confused if I should do what I did below, or
1) IEnumerable results = 
or 
2) List all the values I want in the Select statement (and if I do it that way, I'm still looking for how you loop through the results).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
           XElement xelGOT =
              new XElement("GameOfThrones",
                 new XElement("Characters",
                     new XElement("Character",
                         new XAttribute("Status", "deceased"),
                         new XElement("Name", "Daenerys Targaryen"),
                         new XElement("Actor", "Emilia Clarke")
                         ),
                     new XElement("Character",
                         new XAttribute("Status", "living"),
                         new XElement("Name", "Jon Snow"),
                         new XElement("Actor", "Kit Harrington")
                         ),
                     new XElement("Character",
                         new XAttribute("Status", "living"),
                         new XElement("Name", "Tyrion Lannister"),
                         new XElement("Actor", "Peter Dinklage")
                         )
                      )
                );

            // This one works (except for the "orderby") 
            string secondLivingCharacter =
                (from xchar in xelGOT.Elements("Characters").First().Elements("Character")
                 where (string)xchar.Attribute("Status").Value == "living"
                 //orderby xchar.Element("Name")
                 select xchar).ElementAt(1).Value;
            Console.WriteLine("secondLivingCharacter=" + secondLivingCharacter); 

            // Get all the living characters 
            IEnumerable results =   
                (from xchar in xelGOT.Elements("Characters").First().Elements("Character")
                where (string) xchar.Attribute("Status").Value == "living"
                select xchar).Elements();

            foreach (var result in results.Cast<XElement>())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nDebug result=" + result.ToString()); 
                Console.WriteLine(
                          " Character=" + result.Element("Name").Value +
                          " Actor=" + result.Element("Actor").Value +
                          " Status=" + result.Attribute("Status")
                     );
            }

    }
}
```

The desired result is to loop through and print the name/actor of the two matching characters.

Actual Output Results and Error:

```
secondLivingCharacter=Tyrion LannisterPeter Dinklage


    Debug result=<Name>Jon Snow</Name>
    Run-time exception (line 48): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

    Stack Trace:

    [System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
       at Program.Main() :line 48
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    XElement xelGOT =
              new XElement("GameOfThrones",
                 new XElement("Characters",
                     new XElement("Character",
                         new XAttribute("Status", "deceased"),
                         new XElement("Name", "Daenerys Targaryen"),
                         new XElement("Actor", "Emilia Clarke")
                         ),
                     new XElement("Character",
                         new XAttribute("Status", "living"),
                         new XElement("Name", "Jon Snow"),
                         new XElement("Actor", "Kit Harrington")
                         ),
                     new XElement("Character",
                         new XAttribute("Status", "living"),
                         new XElement("Name", "Tyrion Lannister"),
                         new XElement("Actor", "Peter Dinklage")
                         )
                      )
                );

    // This one works (except for the "orderby") 
    string secondLivingCharacter =
        (from xchar in xelGOT.Elements("Characters").First().Elements("Character")
         where xchar.Attribute("Status").Value.Equals("living")
         orderby xchar.Element("Name").value descending
         select xchar).ElementAt(1).Value;
    Console.WriteLine("secondLivingCharacter='{0}'{1}", secondLivingCharacter, Environment.NewLine);

    // Get all the living characters 
    var results =
        (from xchar in xelGOT.Descendants("Character")
         where (string)xchar.Attribute("Status").Value == "living"
         select xchar);

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Character='{0}' Actor='{1}' Status='{2}'"
             , result.Element("Name").Value
             , result.Element("Actor").Value
             , result.Attribute("Status").Value);
    }

}
```